# Rspec collection misunderstanding

Tags: ruby, rspec

Why this test returns me 'TypeError: nil is not a symbol' while it has to pass?
It's from a book.

```
describe "The string" do 
 it "should have 11 simbols" do
  "this string".should have(11)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a mistake in the book. The line should be:

```
"this string".should have(11).symbols
```